# Removing default OS X screensavers from random rotation

Tags: macos, screensaver, xscreensaver

I have a pack of screensavers (XScreenSaver) that I would use in Ubuntu, with a certain number of them selected at random when a screensaver is needed. I have this same pack, now, for OS X Snow Leopard, and I want the same behavior. I installed only the ones I want in the random rotation, but when I tell it to select one at random, it selects one of *all* the screensavers, not just the ones I installed. When I go to remove the built-in ones, the "`-`" button is disabled, so I don't seem to be able to remove these from the rotation. I would prefer to not have an ugly pan/zoom slideshow of islands or flowers or whatever show up on my computer. **How do I disable the default OS X 10.6 screensavers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable them you'll need to remove them from `/System/Library/Screen Savers`. Remove `Beach.slideSaver`, `Nature Patterns.slideSaver`, `Forest.slideSaver` and any others you don't wish to appear.

(It is probably wisest to move them to some other folder for safe-keeping.)

Comment: It seems you cannot delete these directories in Catalina.  I get `Operation not permitted`, even using sudo.